# Failing to import OCMock headers into iOS project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ocmock

I'm trying to add OCMock to my current project using the instructions at
[ocmock.org](http://ocmock.org).

1. Added the library and the headers to the project.
2. Made sure that the `libOCMock.a` is added to my test target.
3. Added the search path to the header files in `Header Search Paths` under `Build Settings` for the test target.
4. Added the flags `-force_load`, `PATH/TO/libOCMock.a` and `-ObjC` to `Other Linker Flags` (also to the test target).
5. Finally I import the headers in a test class like this: `#import <OCMock/OCMock.h>`

The first thing that happens is that Xcode complains about not finding the headers. If I go ahead and try to build the test target I get an error: `OCMock/OCMock.h` not found.

When I check the build output I can se that it is adding the correct search path: `-I/Users/username/Development/proj/iphone/frameworks/OCMock_2_0_1/headers`

When I list the path in the terminal I can clearly see the files there.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. 
<3

Comment: What exactly did you add to the header search paths?

Comment: Exactly: "$(SRCROOT)/../frameworks/OCMock_2_0_1/headers/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it with the help of a friend (thank you so much A.)!

I had changed the name of the folder that contained the headers to `headers` while the import was pointing to `OCMock/OCmock.h`. :/